# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException and SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've found this crash in crash logs. I don't know when it is happening. Can someone give me advice what is the reason? Maybe someone has same crash.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:787)
       at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:814)
       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeSetXml(XmlUtils.java:350)
       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml(XmlUtils.java:688)
       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:295)
       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:264)
       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:230)
       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:187)
       at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:597)
       at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
       at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:512)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Spend a moment understanding `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: post your code to be more clear

Comment: @Aakash I can't post code because I don't know line of code and when it happen. I get this log from crashlytics

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We had seen this exception when using the SharedPreferences `getStringSet` method. This method returns a set that **should not be modified**. Modifying this set while the SharedPreferences object is being serialized to flash will produce a ConcurrentModificationException.

This will also happen if you use `getAll` and modify the returned map.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Wow, did not expect that. Thank you for the hint! Maybe one should read the doc more often...

Answer (score 0):

Someone have already answered this question, you might be interested to take a look at: 
[ConcurrentModificationException in Android while accessing Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512904/abnormal-concurrentmodificationexception-in-android/33409121#33409121)